# How do I utilize file I/O in order to create a letter?

Tags: java, file-io

I am on the very beginner stage of File I/O so I have no idea how to take just bits and pieces of a line in order to retrieve certain aspects of the input such as the firstName, LastName, Address and what not. I have only done very beginner things such as taking an entire line, and outputting it into a text file. The first text file contains information such as this to be used as an input file:

```
FirstNameFXO|LastFXO|2510 Main Street|Suite 101D|City100|GA|72249|$280.80
FirstNamePNR|LastPNR|396 Main Street|Suite 100A|City102|GA|24501|$346.01
FirstNameXZU|LastXZU|2585 Main Street|Suite 107C|City101|GA|21285|$859.40
FirstNameHWD|LastHWD|1019 Main Street|Suite 102D|City105|GA|28273|$317.12
FirstNameGHP|LastGHP|2097 Main Street|Suite 109B|City106|GA|72621|$279.28
```

Here is what the output is supposed to look like, Would the solution be creating an if statement that would be used every time there is a column that appears? So in psuedocode form:

if (input reads "|") {

Retrieve that part of the input

}

This is what the second text file is supposed to become with me replacing each components with the input from the first file. I am trying to figure out what the solution would be.

```
Dear FirstNameXMI LastXMI,

       Our records shows unpaid balance of $724.78 that is over 120+ days old. 
   The balance due is now. If the balance is not fully paid in ten days 
   (by 3/27/2017), we will have to inform the collection agent for outstanding 
   balance plus %10 processing fee that increases total amount to $797.26.

       If you have any questions or like to discuss a payment plan, please do 
   not hesitate our office at 555-555-5555.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse values from each line you can use `split()`.

```
String str = "FirstNameFXO|LastFXO|2510 Main Street|Suite 101D|City100|GA|72249|$280.80";
String[] values = string.split("|");
String firstName = values[0]; // FirstNameFXO
String lastName = values[1]; // LastFXO
```

Then, your letter could start with something like this:

```
String letter = "Dear " + firstName + " " + lastName + ",";
```